# Peewee ORM JSONField for MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, orm, peewee

I have a [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) model like so:

```
class User(peewee.Model):
    name = peewee.CharField(unique=True)
    some_json_data = peewee.CharField()
    requested_at = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

I know that peewee doesn't support a JSONField for a MySQL DB, but anyway, I though if I could just convert it to a string format and save to db, I can retrieve it as is.

Let's say, for example, this is my JSONField that I am writing to the DB:

```
[
  {
    'name': 'abcdef',
    'address': 'abcdef',
    'lat': 43176757,
    'lng': 42225601
  }
]
```

When I fetch this (JSONField) data, the output is like so:

```
u'[{u\'name\': u\'abcdef\',  u\'address\': u\'abcdef\', u\'lat\': 43176757, u\'lng\': 42225601\'}]'
```

Trying a simplejson load of this is giving me an error like so:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:
>   line 1 column 3 (char 2)

I've tried json dumps of the json data before entering it to the DB and seeing if something would work, but still I have no luck with that.

I am looking for a solution that involves peewee's [custom field](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#custom-fields) options and I want to stick my MySQL. Can someone guide me?

Comment: from now, you can use `JSONField` from `playhouse.mysql_ext`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What's probably happening in your code is Peewee is calling `str()` (or `unicode()`) on the value instead of dumping it to JSON, so the Python string representation is being saved to the database. To do JSON manually, just `import json` and then call `json.dumps(obj)` when you're setting the field and `json.loads(db_value)` when you fetch the field.

It looks like there's a Peewee playhouse extension defined for certain databases (SQLite, PostgreSQL?) that defined a `JSONField` type -- see [JSONField docs here](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#JSONField).

Alternatively, I don't think it'd be hard to define a custom `JSONField` type which does the json loads/dumps automatically. There's a simple example of this in [playhouse/kv.py](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/dc0ac68f3a596e27e117698393b4ab64d2f92617/playhouse/kv.py):

```
class JSONField(TextField):
    def db_value(self, value):
        return json.dumps(value)

    def python_value(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            return json.loads(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the [`JSONField`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/sqlite_ext.html#JSONField) field from Peewee's playhouse?

```py
from playhouse.sqlite_ext import *
db = SqliteExtDatabase(':memory:')
class KV(Model):
     key = TextField()
     value = JSONField()
     class Meta:
         database = db

KV.create_table()
```

It takes care of converting Python objects to JSON, and viceversa:

```py
KV.create(key='a', value={'k1': 'v1'})
KV.get(KV.key == 'a').value # print {'k1': 'v1'}
```

You can query using the JSON keys:

```py
KV.get(KV.value['k1'] == 'v1').key # print 'a'
```

You can easily update JSON keys:

```py
KV.update(value=KV.value.update({'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'})).execute() # add keys to JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL/MariaDB try this library: [jsonfield](https://github.com/mark99i/jsonfield)
It does everything the same as in other answers, only a little more convenient in syntax